# How to aggregate with elasticsearch without query when wanting to add range?

Tags: elasticsearch

Below code works if I didn't remove query from the search, but I don't really need to have the result of the query just the aggregation. How would I be able to add range to the date histogram?

```
await client.search({
    index: "console-*",
    body: {
      sort: {
        "@timestamp": {
          order: "desc"
        }
      },
      // query: {
      //   range: {
      //     "@timestamp": {
      //       gte: Date.now() - 15 * 60 * 1000,
      //       format: "epoch_millis"
      //     }
      //   }
      // },
      aggs: {
        series: {
          date_histogram:{
            field: "@timestamp",
            interval: "30s",
            time_zone: "Asia/Shanghai",
            min_doc_count: 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    size: 0
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you still want the histogram to be filtered by range I would recommend to keep the query as it is. Since you don't want the documents matching the query to be returned and all you want is the aggregation result, all you have to do is set `"size": 0` as below:

```
await client.search({
    index: "console-*",
    body: {
      sort: {
        "@timestamp": {
          order: "desc"
        }
      },
      query: {
        range: {
          "@timestamp": {
            gte: Date.now() - 15 * 60 * 1000,
            format: "epoch_millis"
          }
        }
      },
      aggs: {
        series: {
          date_histogram:{
            field: "@timestamp",
            interval: "30s",
            time_zone: "Asia/Shanghai",
            min_doc_count: 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    size: 0
  });
```

**UPDATE: using filter aggregation**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filterdSeries": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-15m",
            "format": "epoch_millis"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "series": {
            "date_histogram": {
              "field": "@timestamp",
              "interval": "30s",
              "time_zone": "Asia/Shanghai",
              "min_doc_count": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am using right now, but it looks a bit silly in my opinion.

Comment: If you add filter in histogram that will have the same result for the aggregation but in that case the query will be equivalent to `match_all` query and still you will get document based on this.

Comment: Would you like to explain why it's silly? If you don't like the Date math, you can use `now-15m`

Comment: @a.l. Is your question to OP or me?

Comment: @NishantSaini, It's to OP. sorry to bother you. btw, your answer is excellent, can't agree any more.

Comment: How would I use filter? I just don't like to have query written in my search when I don't actually need them, it feels less "pro."

Comment: To use filter you'll need to do nesting of aggregations i.e. you'll have a filter aggregation and inside this histogram aggregation. This will be less efficient.

Comment: Sure but I need to do nested aggregation anyway, currently I do multiple aggregations with different queries, can you provide a working example of nested aggregations to solve this question?

Comment: Updated in answer the raw query required. You can implement the same in the respective elastic client.

Comment: Thx! I did figure this out by myself 2 days ago just after I replied to your comment, but your answer is much appreciated.